# Exclude path params from actuator metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring boot application that uses the actuator metrics and I have the following issue:

I have an endpoint like this :

```
GET /users/{userId}
```

So every time I call this endpoint I use a different Id to get the specific user as you can think we can have hundreds of thousands. It is working correct, but i noticed that when calling my metrics endpoint :

```
GET /metrics
```

I get something like this:

```
counter.status.200.metrics: 1,
counter.status.200.api.users.4: 2,
counter.status.200.api.users.2: 3,
counter.status.200.api.users.3: 2,
```

So it makes me think that i will get a counter for every single call with different path params, so my question is how can i have a counter just for the endpoint `/users/{anyId}` and not for every single combination excluding the parameters?.

--- EDIT ---

I'm using Spring boot + Jersey (I'm not using Spring MVC), the following is my controller code:

```
@Component
@Path("/users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    public Response getUsers() {
        return Response.ok("It works !").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response getUserById(@PathParam("userId") String id) {
        return Response.ok("It works !").build();
    }

}
```

And the following is the Jersey configuration:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(UserResource.class);
        register(PingResource.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. it just returns like this `counter.status.200.api.users : 2`. Can you show your controller code, and also which version of spring-boot are you using

Comment: Sure let me edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5875) with Spring Boot 1.x when using Jersey. There's a workaround [described in the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5875#issuecomment-263294954), alternatively you can disable the metrics filter by adding the following to `application.properties`:

```
endpoints.metrics.filter.enabled=false
```

Comment: With this now i don't have any metric, is it possible to have something like this counter.status.200.api.users : 2 instead of counter.status.200.api.users.2: 3 or I have to remove it and create my own metrics ?

Comment: You could try the workaround that I linked to in my answer.